# Delete files except n files with the "bigger" name?

Tags: shell-script, files

I want to create a shell script that deletes old release files except last n files. In other words, only mantain last n releases when I deploy a new release.

File names have this format:

```
appname_releasenumber_date.tar.gz
```

Maybe there's an easy soluction to do this, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

I've found this solution [Cleaner way to delete files on Linux which include a datestamp as part of file name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70367/cleaner-way-to-delete-files-on-linux-which-include-a-datestamp-as-part-of-file-n) but I need to generate some files first in order to keep the number of files I want to.

Comment: What's the format for the date component in the file names?

Comment: Are all the files for the same appname in the directory or can they be with different appname?

Comment: -2012-06-11_14-57-37.tar.gz -> year-month-day_hours-minutes-seconds.tar.gz

Comment: appname is always the same, but thanks anyway I got to the correct answer thanks to salton one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search oldest files and then you can check if total number of files are more then N files then delete oldest files first in a script or you can also simply use the following example. Let's say you don't want to delete last 3 latest files:

`ls -t1  | tail -n +4 | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: This assumes that the modification times are right—may not be the case depending on how the files got there. (E.g., generated from a version control branch will usually have the date it was generated, or possibly even copied to the server, not the date of the most recent change)

Comment: Yes, I assumed that build script generating this release in a directory and no manual copy is taking place.

Comment: i did an order modification and got to the result, thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

I am going to change the answer by @Salton to make it more general:

```
ls -1 | sort -t_ -n -k2 | head -$((`ls | wc -l`-1)) | xargs rm -rf
```

This one sorts on version number and ignores the date completely.  So, if an older version has a newer date, the older version will be removed.

Comment: quite a pro answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, if your versions are in lexicographic order:

```
rm -f appname_*.tar.gz(N[1,-$((n+1))])
```

The [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `[NUM1,NUM2]` retains only the matches from NUM1 to NUM2. With a minus sign, the number counts from the end (-1 is the last match), so `[1,-$((n+1))]` matches all but the last `$n` files. The glob qualifier `N` says that it's ok if there is no match (which happens if there are no more than `$n` files already).

If the versions aren't in lexicographic order, you may need to sort the files in a different order. The glob qualifier `n` sorts decimal numbers by value, so this will work correctly if you have `appname_9_somedate` followed by `appname_10_someotherdate`.

```
rm -f appname_*.tar.gz(nN[1,-$((n+1))])
```

If you have more complex version numbers, you can specify your own sort function. Write a zsh function `version_less` that returns 0 if its first argument is less than its second argument, and use

```
rm -f appname_*.tar.gz(N[1,-$((n+1))]o+version_less)
```

---

In any shell, if the order of the files is lexicographic order, you can iterate through the matches.

```
set appname_*.tar.gz
while [ $# -gt $n ]; do
  rm "$1"
  shift
done
```

If you need a different order, parsing the output of `ls` is your best bet. Note that `ls` mangles non-printable characters in file names, but in your case that shouldn't be a problem.